# Python, National Stock Exchange, Stock Market, nsepy, nsetools api

Tags: python-3.x, finance, stock

I am trying to make a Python program to get real-time stock/share prices of the National Stock Exchange. For this, I am using NSETOOLS API. 
Here is my code for that:

```
from nsetools import Nse
info = nse.get_quote('RELIANCE')
print(info)
print("Last Traded Price: ", info["lastPrice"])
```

But I am not getting the Last Traded Price of stock in real-time.

Please help me with that.

My targets are:
1) Getting Last Traded Price of the stock in real-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use while  loop with time.sleep(seconds)
Also, you will have to define nse, use this:
`nse = Nse()`

```
from nsetools import Nse
import time 
nse = Nse()
info = nse.get_quote('RELIANCE')
i = 1
while i == 1:
print(info)
print("Last Traded Price: ", info["lastPrice"])
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Thank you, @Mehdi for your support. :)